# Complex numbers $z$ such that $n-z$ and $n+z$ are Gaussian primes

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, gaussian-integers

Is it known whether for all large enough positive integer $n$, there exists a complex number $z$ such that $\vert z\vert<n$ and both $n-z$ and $n+z$ are Gaussian primes? If yes, are there results about the upper bound of their argument?

Comment: To make sure I understand correctly: let's say $n = 1000$. What would $z$ be?

Comment: I don't know if such a $z$ exists, that is precisely what I'm asking.

Comment: Say $A$, $B$ and $I$ are the points of the complex plane of respective affixes $n-z$, $n+z$ and $n$. I want $I$ to be the middle of $[AB]$, the distance $AB$ to be less than $2n$, and $A$ and $B$ located at Gaussian primes.

Comment: We have to find sufficiently small $a,b$ such that both $(n-a)^2+b^2$ and $(n+a)^2+b^2$ are prime. It seems that we can find small pairs $(a,b)$ for every large $n$ , lets say , $n\ge 1000$, but it will be hard to prove this.

Comment: So $r=2na$ should be a primality radius of $n^2+a^2+b^2$.

Comment: If I programmed it correctly, there is no such $z$ for $n = 1000$. For $n - z$ I'm getting an empty `Vector` and for $n + z$ also an empty `Vector`. I'm gonna try a smaller $n$, like maybe $n = 100$...

Comment: Or maybe I did misunderstand. Do you consider $1000 \pm 9i$ a valid example?

Comment: And for $n = 100$, I'm getting $100 \pm 3i$, $98 - 5i$ and $102 + 5i$, $97 - 2i$ and $103 + 2i$, $94 - 5i$ and $106 + 5i$, $91 - 4i$ and $109 + 4i$.

Comment: @Peter: in the equivalent form you have, does $z=a+bi$?

Comment: @Robert Soupe: if $1000+9i$ and $1000-9i$ are Gaussian primes, this fits my requirements.

Comment: @SylvainJulien yes, exactly that

Comment: Yes, because their common norm, 1000081, is prime in $\mathbb Z$. Then this might be a way to at least get an answer on a very specific case. If $z = yi$ is purely imaginary, maybe it's always possible to find the conjugate pair $n \pm yi$ that is prime.